# Running each kernel function on multiple gpus in cuda 10.0

Tags: cuda, gpu

```
// Four Kernel Runs Simultaneously
Kernel1 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 0
Kernel2 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 1
Kernel3 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 2
Kernel4 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 3
```

I want it to work like this code.

Do you have any samples or document for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cudaSetDevice(int device)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb) before each kernel call.

> `__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaSetDevice ( int  device )`
>       Set device to be used for GPU executions.

```
// Four Kernel Runs Simultaneously
cudaSetDevice(0);
Kernel1 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 0
cudaSetDevice(1);
Kernel2 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 1
cudaSetDevice(2);
Kernel3 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 2
cudaSetDevice(3);
Kernel4 <<< numBlocks, threadPerBlock >>> (args); // GPU 3
```

Comment: Just doing that won't guarantee everything works. You really need to crate a stream on each device and launch kennels into that stream

Comment: Does it ensure Simultaneously? It's likely to work serially.

Comment: To run it simultaneously you need to create custom streams and run kernels using streams.

Comment: actually this is all that is needed, to allow kernels running on separate devices to overlap.  The default stream is sufficient, because streams are a per-device construct, and stream semantics indicate that kernels launched into separate streams may overlap.  Default stream semantics  (i.e. synchronization)  do not apply here because they only synchronize activities *per-device*.